# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Name'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, crud

Hola estoy trabajando con **ASP.NET** tratando de hacer un nuevo objeto de **categories** a partir de otras clases y según yo estoy pasando todos los parametros pertinentes de ambas clases. Pero al parecer estoy errando en algo no sé si es por como lo estoy pasando o si definitvamente no lo estoy pasando bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
//CategoriesController
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize]
public async Task < ActionResult > Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Description")] Categories category) {
  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    db.Category.Add(category);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }

  return View(category);
}


//model

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PCotiza_compras.Models {
  public class Categories {
    public int Id {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
    public string Name {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Descripción")]
    public string Description {
      get;
      set;
    }

  }

}

//model CategoriesDepartmentViewModel




namespace PCotiza_compras.Models {
  public class CategoriesDepartmentViewModel {
    [Display(Name = "Departamentos")]
    public List < Departments > DepartmentItem {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Categorias")]
    public Categories CategoriesItem {
      get;
      set;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
@*@model PCotiza_compras.Models.Categories*@ @model PCotiza_compras.Models.CategoriesDepartmentViewModel @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Categories", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "modalCategories" })) {
<div class="modal-body" style="overflow:hidden;">

  @Html.AntiForgeryToken() @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) @* Select del departamento *@

  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentItem, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-10" })
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <select class="form-control" id="Departamento" name="Departamento">
                        @foreach (var d in Model.DepartmentItem)
                        {
                            <option value="@d.Id">@d.Code - @d.Description</option>
                        }
                    </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoriesItem.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-10" })
    <div class="col-md-12">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoriesItem.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoriesItem.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoriesItem.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-10" })
    <div class="col-md-12">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoriesItem.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoriesItem.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
  <input id="buttonNewCategory" type="submit" value="Crear" class="btn btn-success" />
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En tu post, en el método de acción (Action Method) estas queriendo recibir un elemento del tipo Categories, pero tu modelo es del tipo CategoriesDepartmentViewModel. Tu html form está enviando elemento con id CategoriesItem_Name.

Básicamente necesitas cambiar el tipo de objeto que estas recibiendo:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Description")] CategoriesDepartmentViewModel categoriesDepartmentViewModel)
{
    Categories category = categoriesDepartmentViewModel.CategoriesItem != null ? categoriesDepartmentViewModel.CategoriesItem : new Categories();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Category.Add(category);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(category);
}
```

*PD1: El ejemplo obtiene la categoría en un if de una sola línea, este es opcional y lo puedes modificar. Lo importante en la respuesta es el tipo de objeto esperado en el método de acción.
PD2: Ojo con el modelo que estas pasando de regreso a su vista. Según entiendo tiene que ser del tipo CategoriesDepartmentViewModel*